# mysql autoincrement id vs php generated id

Tags: php, mysql

until now i ve always stored records in mysql database by generating an ID (varchar 32 primary key) with php, with a function like that:

```
$id = substr( str_shuffle( abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 ), 0, 8 );
```

but until now in mysql DB i've always use utf8_bin (that is case sensitive) now i'm using utf8_general_ci (case insensitive).

I have a table in my DB to store statistics, in this table there are a millions of records.

in this case is better to use: 'id int unsigned autoincrement' as primary key?

if yes, is possibile that if many users call the sciprt at the same time the script crash with a 'duplicate id' error? and how i can avoid that?

Comment: It is **always** better to use an auto-incremented id of the DB.

Comment: database autoincrement will __not__ duplicate ids, no matter how many users are calling the script at the same time: it was designed precisely for that purpose

Comment: As usual, you'll have to define "better". UUIDs (which your random string is not) are unique across servers, incremental IDs are (normally) not. What are your specs?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario MySQL can be configured (for example odd/even id's for two servers) to be unique across servers. PHP-generated uid's will fail if there are concurring transactions. I think in any case properly configured DBMS sequence uid is the best solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though several people can access the site at once, but MySQL will process inserts in the table sequentially and will queue requests it receives. So in the insert query, if an ID is not provided an auto-incremented ID will be generated and then the row saved and committed. And the next request in queue will be processed. There is no way an auto-incremented ID can be as such duplicated.

Additionally, your code generates a random string and not an unique string. There is a lot of difference between the two. It is quite possible to generate a random string sequence that has been generated earlier.

On the other hand auto-increment is a gradually increasing sequential no ensuring there is no chance of having a duplicate key. As such it is always advised to use auto-increment to generate a primary key than generate one's own.

To get the last generated MySQL ID you can use [mysqli_insert_id()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) right after your insert query in PHP and use it in your code for subsequent interactions with MySQL with respect to the inserted row.

Answer (score 0):

At my opinion a autoincrement with mysql is better, because your php script now could be visited by more than one person at the same time. 
So the id is maybe not unique anymore.
And I am pretty sure that mysql is so well programmed that it prohibit same ids ;)

Comment: thx, if i've 3 records on my table (with ID: 1,2 and 3) then 10 users visiting my website at the same time, is not possibile that mysql autoincrement set ID = 4 for each one? sure?

Comment: Actually I don't find a website for this, BUT mysql is using in big projects. And I think if mysql is running one ONE server mysql can't be insert 2 entries at the same time so it is not possible to have the ID=4 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

In fact your current code has the bug that the same ID might be generated again. MySQL generated id doesn't have this problem. Even if you have a reason to generate your own ids, I would still use MySQL autoincrement integer to link between tables because of better indexing (speed).

And if for example you want to hide the sequence from the user, keep it in separate column with unique index. And do the id generation and insert in do while loop so if you happen to generate the same id second time, you can retry.